# Is there nodejs forum engine like punbb/phpbb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forum, phpbb, punbb

I've googled / searched npm and have been surprised that there aren't any punbb/phpbb forum engines on top of nodejs.

If you know one, plz share a link to